# how to import data into rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 application with a User class, and a tab-delimited file of users that I want to import.

How do I get access to the Active Record model outside the rails console, so that I can write a script to do

```
require "???active-record???"

File.open("users.txt", "r").each do |line|
    name, age, profession = line.strip.split("\t")
    u = User.new(:name => name, :age => age, :profession => profession)
    u.save
end
```

Do I use the "ar-extensions" gem, or is there another way? (I don't particularly care about speed right now, I just want something simple.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can write a rake method to so.
Add this to a my_rakes.rake file in your_app/lib/tasks folder:

```
  desc "Import users." 
  task :import_users => :environment do
    File.open("users.txt", "r").each do |line|
      name, age, profession = line.strip.split("\t")
      u = User.new(:name => name, :age => age, :profession => profession)
      u.save
    end
  end
```

An then call `$ rake import_users` from the root folder of your app in Terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Use the **[activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import)** gem for bulk importing.

Install via your Gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord-import'
```

Collect your users and import:

```
desc "Import users." 
task :import_users => :environment do
  users = File.open("users.txt", "r").map do |line|
    name, age, profession = line.strip.split("\t")
    User.new(:name => name, :age => age, :profession => profession)
  end
  User.import users
end
```

Comment: What about if I want to check if the entry exists and perform an update if it does. If it is a new entry I would want to create it. Not sure this would work with mapping?