# Rails 3, activerecord-import gem, CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704065/how-to-import-data-into-rails)  I have this rake task:

```
desc "Import sales" 
task :import_sales => :environment do
  sales = File.open(Rails.root.join("public", "system", "xmls", "3", "original", "first.csv"),"r").map do |line|
    isbn, date, quantity, value, channel = line.split("\,")
    Importsale.new(:isbn => isbn, :date => date, :quantity => quantity, :value => value, :channel => channel)
  end
  Importsale.import sales
end
```

and some csv data like this:

```
9780953893201,30/5/10,4,25.6,UK Home
9780953893201,25/6/10,3,19.2,UK Home
9780953893201,30/7/10,6,95.94,UK Home
9780953893201,27/8/10,1,15.99,Export
9780953893201,27/8/10,13,207.87,UK Home
9780953893201,27/8/10,1,6.4,UK Home
9780953893201,24/9/10,14,223.86,UK Home
9780953893201,24/9/10,5,32,UK Home
```

But the rake task is not splitting the CSV file - I'm getting one record imported, with the last channel containing.

```
UK Home
9780953893201
```

Is the use of map stopping the csv parsing as lines? If I use each or each_line I get an 'invalid arguments' error.

Comment: Maybe you want File.readlines(...).map do |line| ?

Comment: You did it! Thank you. Bung it down as an answer if you like and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one is writing the answer...

```
File.readlines(...).map do |line|
    ...
end
```